DevExpress HTML tab of ASPxHtmlEditor isn't loaded
After DevExpress v20 update HTML tab isn't loaded when I click on the HTML tab, the Design tab is perfectly fine loaded but not the HTML tab. The content is loaded for page so that's not a problem, it might be a CSS or JavaScript issue.
